# Pure For vs. ES6 Map | Which one to choose?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I love writing Pure For(nested Fors) in JavaScript instead of using map because i learnt its better than Map in performance. Is it **True** or i'm making a mistake over and over again?

If **For** is faster, **Map** is cleaner, but which is better to select?

Because i'm not good in **ES6 Map**, can anyone write below code with map in cleaner way?

```
let categoriesDataArray = [];
let productsDataArray = [];
if (!this.props.categoriesIsFetching) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.props.categories.length; i += 1) {
    for (let j = 0; j < this.props.products.length; j += 1) {
      if (
        this.props.categories[i]._id === this.props.products[j].category_id
      ) {
        productsDataArray.push(this.props.products[j]);
      }
    }
    categoriesDataArray.push({
      title: this.props.categories[i].title,
      data: productsDataArray
    });
    productsDataArray = [];
  }
}
```

Comment: `can anyone write below code` - SO is not a code writing service - you try, see where you fail, then ask why you fail

Comment: @JaromandaX: Don't forget teh two steps before "ask why you fail" "research thoroughly" and "search throughly on SO" (somewhat redundant, but...). :-)

Comment: Please don't **randomly** boldface **parts** of your question, it only hinders readability. Also, when referring to methods, since case is significant, please use the correct case (`map`), not least because JavaScript also has `Map`, which is something else entirely.

Comment: "ES6 `Map`" means the data structure, right? The array `.map` method is available since ES5.

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm not going to use people to writing for me codes ;) i'm just wonder which is better as i wrote in my question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, i'm sorry. i mean map for arrays.

Comment: Then consider updating the question. 'ES6 Map' stands for `Map` unambiguously. Array map is `map`, and there's nothing ES6 about it - it's ES5. You're asking about ES5 features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The absolute best Performance ain't always the biggest concern. Do you really care about shaving off 1-2 ms of a task that runs once a minute? To me, readability and avoiding bugs are more important.

> If **For** is faster, **Map** is cleaner, but which is better to select?

always cleaner, untill you run into actual performance issues. And then debug where the performance issues come from; not just blind refactoring and *"optimizing"*.

---

But your code has a bigger performance problem than `for` vs `map`. Your approach with the nested loops.

Your code has to iterate over all products for every single category.

```
let categoriesDataArray = [];

if(!this.props.categoriesIsFetching){   
    categoriesDataArray = this.props.categories.map(category => {
        return {
            title: category.title,
            data: this.props.products.filter(product => product.category_id === category._id)
        }
    });
}
```

And again, sometimes this is OK. It is simple, it is expressive ... but as the arrays are getting bigger, the execution time for this will rapidly increase. 
Then, using a different approach will be more benefitial than the discussion for-loops or Array#map

You can do the same task by iterating once over each array and using a map. A runtime of `O(n+m)` instead of `O(n*m)`.

```
let categoriesDataArray = [];

if(!this.props.categoriesIsFetching){
    const productsByCategoryId = {};

    categoriesDataArray = this.props.categories.map(category => {
        return {
            title: category.title,
            data: productsByCategoryId[category._id] = []
        }
    });

    this.props.products.forEach(product => {
        if(product.category_id in productsByCategoryId)
            productsByCategoryId[product.category_id].push(product);
    });
}
```

or as loops:

```
let categoriesDataArray = [];

if(!this.props.categoriesIsFetching){
    const productsByCategoryId = {};

    for(let i=0; i<this.props.categories.length; ++i){
        let category = this.props.categories[i];
        let data = [];

        productsByCategoryId[category.__id] = data;
        categoriesDataArray[i] = {
            title: category.title,
            data: data
        }
    }

    for(let j=0; j<this.products.categories.length; ++j){
        let product = this.products.categories[j];

        if(product.category_id in productsByCategoryId){
            productsByCategoryId[product.category_id].push(product);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas, I'll consider using clean way from now.

Answer (score 1):

es6 map is cleaner and let you avoid unwanted scope error / object mutations, never used again for and forEach after switch to es6

Comment: You definitely still should use `for … of` when it's not your intention to create a new array. You can even use it with `const` declarations for block scope.

Comment: In this case him want to create a new array from existing, in this case Array.filter() will do the job

Answer (score 1):

For loops are indeed faster most of the time.
You can try it yourself: 
https://jsperf.com/map-vs-for-loop-performance/2

My suggestion: Make use of all the great JavaScript features that you can find and use a code optimizer like [Google Closure](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) or Babel (with the right plugins e.g. [babel-plugin-loop-optimizer](https://github.com/vihanb/babel-plugin-loop-optimizer)) to compile the code into something that runs way faster.

Here is another example of how much of a difference it can make to go with one looping method over another: https://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/37
So yeah, use an optimizer if you can.

Comment: Don't forget to ask self: How many times am I iterating 10,000 items 21,000 times per second. And do I need to do that? Sometimes the performance consideration doesn't lie simply in the syntax. P.S. Agreed with you on your suggestion - and that is a nice plugin!