# Fastest way to loop through an object array and get specific keys

Tags: javascript

Say I have this array:

```
Dogs = [
    {Name: 'Sparky', OwnerID: 1},
    {Name: 'Pooch', OwnerID: 2},
    {Name: 'Sneak', OwnerID: 1}
]
```

What is the fastest way for me to do this:

```
dogNames = Dogs.map(element => element.Name);
```

I was just wondering if there is something like this:

```
dogNames = Dogs[...Name];
```

Comment: What's wrong with `Dogs.map(element => element.Name)`? You could do `Dogs.map(({Name})=> Name)` but that's not much of an improvement. The syntax you're proposing is not possible

Comment: `Name` is unknow for spreading.

Comment: @adiga Well I feel like these is something like `[...]` to use?
@NinaScholz that was just an example...

Comment: Are the names unique?  Why don't you just create an associative array/object?  Get rid of the array altogether and just create one large object.  Then its just Dogs['Sparky'], where your object would change to {'Sparky':1,'Pooch':2,'Sneak':1}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pure For vs. ES6 Map | Which one to choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48186083/pure-for-vs-es6-map-which-one-to-choose)

Comment: @SPlatten The Dogs array is just a simplified version. My arrays are much more detailed

Comment: @FreddyBonda, so instead of :1, change to :{} and put the detail into the object associated with the name.

Comment: @SPlatten that's besides the point, it's not what OP's asking. They're asking if there's a concise way of obtaining a list of arbitrary object members' values.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, no, I disagree, the OP is asking for the fastest way to access the data, I am putting forward a faster method than the adopted array.

Comment: @SPlatten we agree to disagree then :) Freddy can you please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a closure over the wanted key an map the result of only a single property.

```js
const only = k => o => o[k];

var dogs = [{ Name: 'Sparky', OwnerID: 1 }, { Name: 'Pooch', OwnerID: 2 }, { Name: 'Sneak', OwnerID: 1 }],
    dogNames = dogs.map(only('Name'));
    
console.log(dogNames);
```

Comment: If you measure the time from creating the array, converting it to a map then performing the look up compared to referencing an object instead of an array I think the results will be very clear....I don't think converting an array to a map is going to offer much of an increase in performance.

Comment: in sense of performance you are right. in sense of writing code, not.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by saying "fastest". Do you mean execution time? Fastest to type? Easiest to understand?

When "fastest to type" and "easiest to understand" is what you mean, then I'd rather say something like `array.map(x => x.prop)` is probably the fastest. You might find a shorter way to type it besides removing the variable and property names, but I can't think of one.

In terms of execution time, most people believe that using loops is the fastest way:

```
let names = [];
for (let i = 0; i < dogs.length; i += 1) {
  names[i] = dogs[i].Name;
}
```

Personally, I avoid loops whenever possible and stick with `map`, `filter`, `reduce` – to be honest, mainly because for most projects *my* execution time is more expensive than the execution time of my *script*.

Anyway, deciding that is up to you.